# Bathroom outlet

Tags: electrical

Our portable AC unit has been plugged into our bathroom for several years. It's now tripping the main breaker. The bathroom outlet has a breaker but it's not tripping it. I think it needs to be replaced but my husband won't listen. If there was any type of over load the outlet would trip not the main.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If you throw the bathroom outlet breaker, does the AC turn off? What's the rating of the bathroom and main breakers?

Comment: That's not weird, different breakers have different trip curves. **Also, if your main breaker is a GFCI or RCD** (very common in much of the world, not the US), then "main breaker tripping not branch" is the *normal* way a ground fault chooses to trip.  Does your main breaker have a "TEST" button on it?

Comment: Does it run for a while then throw the breaker, try to start up but throw the breaker in the middle of the motor failing to start, or does the breaker trip immediately when the A/C is turned on?